# Классы, наследование

Tags: c#

Создал 2 класса. От одного наследовал другой. Вот код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Manager man = new Manager("", "", 0, 0);
    }
}

class Employee
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Employee(string sName, string MyName, int MyAge)
    {
        Surname = sName;
        Name = MyName;
        Age = MyAge;
    }
}

class Manager : Employee
{
    public int Pay { get; set; }

    public Manager(string s, string n, int a, int p)
    {
        Surname = s;
        Name = n;
        Age = a;
        Pay = p;
    }
}
```

В унаследованном классе заполняю напрямую свойства из первого. Но почему то ругается на конструктор класса Manager.

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'sName' of 'Employee.Employee(string,
>   string, int)'

Что то не пойму что не так?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В классе Employee у вас нет конструктора без параметров, так что вы должны явно указать конструктор Employee, соответствующий конструктору Manager, и передать в него параметры. Создать объект класса Employee без вызова конструктора (и, соответственно, без передачи в него параметров) не получится:

```
public Manager(string s, string n, int a, int p) 
    : base(s, n, a) // будет вызван Employee(string, string, int)
{
    // все свойства, кроме Pay, инициалируются в конструкторе базового типа
    Pay = p;
}
```